# USB Stick Not Being Detected in Ubuntu

Tags: usb, mount

I have an Ubuntu laptop running Ubuntu 20.04:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

I'm strangely having problems mounting an external USB stick that I recently purchased. It is getting detected on my Mac, but it is not showing up on my Ubuntu. I formatted it in my Mac (FAT32) and I also do not see any messages being thrown in the dmesg command. It is totally weird. I know that my USB port on my Ubuntu works as I mounted my external HDD and it gets detected. How can I fix this?

Comment: You also see nothing in `sudo fdisk -l"?

Comment: I see the other disks, but not the USB stick!

Comment: Watch `sudo journalctl  --follow` as you plug in tge USB stick.